# fastapi[openapi.json]- swagger pagination issue

Tags: swagger, openapi, fastapi

suddenly the fastapi documentation page messed up,
It looks like this:
[image]

I tried resetting the browser but seems it doesn't relate to the browser ,
as I tried accessing the pages from different clients and it looks the same.

Comment: Fastapi uses openapi style files. It happened to me as well today. The problem is not related to fastapi, but to openapi. I guess they'll fix it soon

Comment: Known issue, see https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7290

Answer (score 0):

I downgrade fastapi to 0.61.0 and it solved this,
for all later versions - same issue .